# Readability: splitting lines of code, should the operator be on the first or second line?

Tags: c++, coding-style, formatting, readability

Simple question about formatting code (in my case C++).

If I have a line of code, say:

```
SomeSortOfLongVariable = AnotherLongVariableThatTakesUpTonsOfHorizontalSpace + IDontActuallyUseVariablesThisLong
```

Should I split it like:

```
SomeSortOfLongVariable = AnotherLongVariableThatTakesUpTonsOfHorizontalSpace +
                         IDontActuallyUseVariablesThisLong
```

or:

```
SomeSortOfLongVariable = AnotherLongVariableThatTakesUpTonsOfHorizontalSpace 
                         + IDontActuallyUseVariablesThisLong
```

Another example:

```
foo = bar->baz;
// Should it be:
foo = bar->
      baz;
//Or:
foo = bar
      ->baz;
```

Do people have a preference when it comes to this? Is it on a case-by-case basis? They both seem equally clear (or unclear) to me, so I was wondering if there are any standard ways of doing it.

Comment: Considering at least one code formatting extension I know of has an option for this, it's a perfect fit for too opinionated.

Comment: Yes, you should split it one of the two ways you show in your example with a `+` sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, people have preferences about this.

No, there's no standard or consensus agreement.  I'm not aware of any especially strong arguments for either side, either.

So like any coding style issue, you can stick with whatever other people who edit the same code have been doing, or just pick one you like.

(I wouldn't even complain about being inconsistent on this issue.)